# locked into a circular reference with templated class

Tags: c++

I have this kind of architecture :

Bar.h

```
#ifndef _testCircularInclusion_bar_h_
#define _testCircularInclusion_bar_h_
#include "foo.h"
#include <string.h>

class Bar{
    public:
        Foo foo;
        Bar() : foo(*this){}
        
        std::string SayHello(){ return "Hello";}
        
};

#endif
```

And now Foo.h:

```
#ifndef _testCircularInclusion_foo_h_
#define _testCircularInclusion_foo_h_
#include <iostream>

class Bar;
#include "bar.h"
class Foo{
    private:
        Bar& bar;
    
    public:
        Foo(Bar& _bar) : bar(_bar){}
        template<class T> T Add(T t , T a);
};


template<class T> T Foo::Add(T t , T a){
    std::cout << bar.SayHello() << "\n"; //when commented my code compile
    return t+a;
}
#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include "bar.h"

int main() {
    Bar bar;
    bar.foo.Add<int>(5,2);
}
```

Here is the error message:
[image: Error message]

And the place it occure :
[image: Where the error occure]

**The question Here is to know if in this case, is it possible to fix this circular reference without removing the bar.SayHello() in Foo::Add(...) ??**

Edit:
I dont have any problem compiling this current code using Miscrosft visual C++ compiler. But when Using CLANGx64 it failled

Comment: thats not possible. Every `Foo` has a member `bar` that has a member `foo`  that has a member `bar` that has a member `foo` .... what are those classes supposed to model? There is nothing that requires such infinite contains relation

Comment: `Bar() : foo(*this){}` wont compile too. A `Bar` is not a `Foo`, and you dereference `this` before the object is constructed

Comment: I'm curently working with a class, lets name it scene, which carry an instance of class named "ObjectManager", this instance allow to create Object in scene. An Object must be bind to a scene. To do this, my scene carry an ObjectManager, and this object Manager carry a Scene reference of is "parent" scene. Then when ObjectManager create an object it will give to the object a reference of Scene. that's why Scene and ObjectManager must carry reference to each other. I dont want to use pointer so I'm trying to perform it using reference

Comment: @idclev463035818 humm, Indeed, I have forget to say Bar is a reference in Foo, I edit to fix the code

Comment: Please include a [mcve] and the error message in the question

Comment: @idclev463035818 I have changed my code to make it correspond perfectly with what I have on my IDE. the question here is to know if their is a way to escape this circulare refrence without having to remove the use of bar.SayHello() in Foo::Add(...)

Comment: And what is the reason that you don’t want to use pointers? Besides the, as `Bar` does not use templates it might be a candidate for the PIMPL idiom.

Comment: @t.niese Since my acutal code use reference instead of pointer I want to know if it is possible to fix my actual problem keeping the reference but if it's not then I will swap to a pointer using the PIMPL idiom

Comment: when the member is a reference it does not change much. My first comment still holds. References always reference something, they cannot reference nothing. It is not clear what relation `Foo` and `Bar` really need. What is "the problem" you are trying to solve? Why can't you remove the `foo` member from `Bar` ? There is too little context to suggest a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of interdependency is best solved by using just one header file:

```
#ifndef INCLUDED_FOO_BAR_H_
#define INCLUDED_FOO_BAR_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Bar;

class Foo{
    private:
        Bar& bar;
    
    public:
        Foo(Bar& _bar) : bar(_bar){}
        template<class T> T Add(T t , T a);
};

class Bar{
public:
    Foo foo;
    Bar() : foo(*this){}
    
    std::string SayHello(){ return "Hello";}
    
};

template<class T> T Foo::Add(T t , T a){
    std::cout << bar.SayHello() << "\n";
    return t+a;
}

#endif
```

If this header file gets large, you can split it up into "private" subpieces such as a file for inline member functions of `Foo` and a file for inline member functions of `Bar`. These would be for inclusion **only** from the "public" header file.

If you really want different public header files "Foo.h" and "Bar.h", you can of course just have one include the other and contain nothing else.

Aside: note your initialization of reference member `bar` is valid by itself, but be careful how it's used within the constructor and destructor of `Foo`. The rules about what is and isn't valid in that sort of case are somewhat complicated. If possible, just make sure the constructor and destructor don't use `bar` at all, except for the `bar(_bar)` initialization.